# How can I style an <input type="range"> inside the shadowtree?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a [custom element](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements) with Javascript and inside my custom element is an input of type range. Now I want to style it but it's not working.

I tried styling the element in Javascript and also in an external CSS file which is linked to my HTML page.
I used `::-webkit-slider-thumb` to style the thumb because I want it to be a circle.

```
(function(){

    const template = document.createElement("template");
    template.innerHTML = `
    <style>

    </style>
    <input type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="0">
    `;

class SliderElement extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();
        let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }

    connectedCallback() {

    }

}

customElements.define('slider-element', SliderElement);

})();
```

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="de">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="js/slider.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <slider-element></slider-element>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to style the `<slider-element>` with `::-webkit-slider-thumb` I expect it to work. It would be good if I could style my custom element in `style.css`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a shadow DOM, styles stop at the "shadow boundary." Styles outside of the shadow root won't apply to elements inside of it. [As per html5rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/#toc-style-scoped) (he's using `h3` elements as an example, emphasis his):

> - There are other h3s on this page, but the only one that matches the
>     h3 selector, and therefore styled red, is the one in the ShadowRoot.
>     Again, scoped styles by default.
> - Other styles rules defined on this page that target h3s don't bleed into my content. That's because **selectors don't cross the shadow boundary**.

So you'll have to define styles for your custom element inside the style tag you included in `template.innerHTML`. For example (I got the styles for the slider from [here](https://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html)):

```
template.innerHTML = `
<style>
    input[type=range]{
        -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
    input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
        width: 300px;
        height: 5px;
        background: #ddd;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
    input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        border: none;
        height: 16px;
        width: 16px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: goldenrod;
        margin-top: -4px;
    }
</style>
<input type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="0">
`;
```

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/04rkda1b/)

Comment: @Alex Did this help at all?